# Take max from multiple grouped data pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am in a loop which gives me a groupby output like below
`df.groupby(['grp1','grp2'])['mycol'].sum()`

Basically I am getting sum of my grouped elements.

```
grp1  grp2 
A     1    10 
B     1    20
C     2    30 
D     3    40 
E     4    50 
      1    60
```

Now in the next iteration I may get a grouped df like below

```
grp1  grp2 
A     1    20 
D     3    40 
E     4    30 
      1    90 
F     1    40
```

I want to take the `max` from each iteration.
So after 2nd iteration I have an output like

```
grp1  grp2 
A     1    20 #because 20 was higher than 10
B     1    20 #carried as it is
C     2    30 #carried as it is
D     3    40 #carried as it is (both were equal)
E     4    30 #because 90+30 >50+60
      1    90 
F     1    40 #added
```

So by the end I have which group reached peak values during say 5 iterations. 
It sounds straight forward ( to keep track of max seen till now), but I am not getting how to approach this. 
I tried doing `df.groupby(['grp1','grp2'])['mycol'].sum().to_dict()` and do something like updating dict on reading new df. (just a try, not sure how to keep dict updated) or maybe there is a simple `pandas and np` solution I still dont know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use groupby again! :-)

1. Concatenate your results ([pd.concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)),
2. Group by the index ([pd.Series.groupby, see `level` param](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html)),
3. Aggregate with `.max()`

Shown in code:

```
res = pd.concat(list_of_iteration_results)
res = res.groupby(level=['grp1', 'grp2']).max()
```

Comment: thanks, but how did `max` knew it has to add then compare ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question :-)
If you inspect `res` after the concatenation, you should see that each index combination can occur many times, e.g. [(A, 1), (B, 1), (A, 1), (A, 1), ...]. This is what we group by with `level`, and then `max` takes the maximum value from each of those groups. Does that answer your question, @pythonRcpp?

Comment: yes I think `level`is doing the trick I was concerned. Thanks I would accept the answer once I run it on my sample data. Very nice answer indeed.. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help :)